# Finding an integer at a given position i in a sequence of increasing and juxtaposing integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Disclosure: This is for homework help**

I want to find an integer at a given position i while repeatedly constructing and adding to a sequence of integers preferably with decent run time and performance.

Comment: Google "sum of first n integers". There's a formula. You can use it to calculate the answer almost instantly.

Comment: It requires a little more work than that though, considering that this is a list of base 10 digits, not a purely arithmetical sequence, on top of still having to reverse engineer it to fit the problem.

Comment: @AlexHall but I'm trying to find a single integer at a given position in a generated sequence though rather than a sum

Comment: I think this is what Izaak is saying. And you're sure that these integers will be in base 10? And the integers start at `1`?

Comment: @quamrana yes, I'm sure. My code does give the correct answer for the question, just that I'm being penalized for the run time being too slow

Comment: Ok, better start caching results.

Comment: There's nothing particularly inefficient in this code. Short of some crazy math formula to instantly calculate the correct result, I'm not sure how to (significantly) reduce the runtime.

Comment: First step is to try to guess the last integer in your list based on `inputpos`. That can use some approximation based on sum of n integers etc. Then you can try `biglist = [str(x) for x in range(1,20)]`, followed by `myseq = "".join( "".join(biglist[:i+1]) for i in range(10) )`. That should be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rebuilding the sub-sequences from 1 at each iteration of the *while* instead of simply keeping a sequence and adding the next number in the following iteration, and then *extend* the main list with that.

Also, you should defer the `str.join` until after the *while* and not build strings at each iteration:

```
from itertools import count

def give_output(digitPos):
    c = count(1)
    l, lst = [], []
    while len(lst) <= digitPos:
        l.append(next(c))  # update previous sub-sequence
        lst.extend(l)
    return int(''.join(map(str, lst))[digitPos-1])
```

---

Timings:

```
In [10]: %%timeit
    ...: giveOutput(500)
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 219 µs per loop

In [11]: %%timeit
    ...: give_output(500)
    ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 126 µs per loop
```

About half the time!

You can even do better if you pick the *i* th item using a div-mod approach instead of building a large string; I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on what you mean by the div-mod approach?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, moving the list and index outside the function might cache your results better:

```
list1 = []
i = 2

def giveOutput():
    global list1
    global i
    digitPos = int(input())

    while len(list1) <= digitPos:

        list1.extend(list(map(int, ''.join(map(str, range(1, i))))))

        i = i + 1

    print(list1[digitPos -1])
```

This only really works well when you are given a number of testcases.

**Update:** (Thanks to Moses for ideas about building up strings)

in fact your lists could just be a strings:

```
all_digits = ''
digits_up_to_i = ''
i = 1

def giveOutput():
    global all_digits
    global digits_up_to_i
    global i
    digitPos = int(input())

    while len(all_digits) <= digitPos:

        digits_up_to_i += str(i)
        all_digits += digits_up_to_i

        i = i + 1

    print(all_digits[digitPos -1])
```

Comment: Doing string concatenation at each iteration of the while is terribly inefficient especially with large strings. Keep the sequence as a list and build the string at the end.